# Save value to Firestore on Stripe successful payment status

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, stripe-payments

I want to write the user free-input form data to Firestore based on them successfully completing the Stripe checkout through the `PaymentElement`. I was first trying to do so based on the `stripe.confirmPayment` method response, which did not work well. Any ideas or practical examples on how can this be implemented? I have also tried using Stripe Webhooks, but I am unsure how to pass the user free-input form data there. Can this generally be handled from the front end, or should I create Firebase function?

```js
const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
  elements,
  confirmParams: {
    return_url: window.location.href
  }
});
```

Comment: could you please share the code of how you tried to use `stripe.confrimPayment` and it didn't work? what was the error?

Comment: @Tarzan, it worked, but I can not access the success status, only the error. Anyways I have updated my question with the code

Comment: if error is undefined (e.g. `if(!error)` or `if(error === undefined)`) then you have successfully confirmed the Payment

Comment: @Tarzan the function does not get to that point for some reason

Comment: Have a look at this stackoverflow link(https://stackoverflow.com/a/72806861/18265638)